# How to make program can get the value of a special character that inputted by the user

Tags: java, unicode, ascii

so i want to make a program that can read special character and change it into other character using caesar chiper. but, i don't understand how actually a special character can be read in java. please teach me. thank you.

Comment: what is a special character?

Comment: Special characters are just characters like all the others, such as the letter `A`. If you know how to read the letter `A`, you know how to read e.g. the character `⬄`. If you're referring to extended characters, such as ``, which are stored as surrogate pairs in Java strings, then you should have said so, and you should have researched UTF-16 surrogate pairs online, before asking here how to work with them in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Character class. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

```
char[] charArray = {'1', ' ', '!', 'a', 'C'};

        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
            char c = charArray[i];
            if(Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
                System.out.println( "'" + c +"'" + " is whitespace");
            } else if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                System.out.println( "'" + c +"'" + " is a number");
            } else if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
                System.out.println( "'" + c +"'" + " is a letter");
            } else { 
                System.out.println( "'" + c +"'" + " must be a special character");
            }
        }
```